# Oracle apex вывод clob в classic report

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Всем привет, задача стоит в том, что бы сделать чат в Oracle apex. Я нашёл статью как делают чат на classic report с шаблоном комментариев. Почти всё работает, кроме одной вещи, он выводит сообщения до 4000х символов. В бд они находятся в формате clob. Как вывести в sql запросе больше 4000х символов или вывести clob? Возможно кто то делал чат и есть другой способ, будет интересно почитать.